# Random View Controller

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

I have twenty six different view controllers. I want to show random View Controller, when i click on button. Also i have classes to every view controller without .xlb file. I tried  this method, but it didn't work.

```
NSString *randomViewControllerClassName = viewControllerList[arc4random() % 99];
UIViewController *randomVC = [[NSClassFromString(randomViewControllerClassName) alloc] init]
[self presentViewController:randomVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

viewControllerList consists of my 26 view controllers.

Comment: %99? you said you only have 26 vc's right?

Comment: What do you mean, "it didn't work"? What result did you get? Be specific.

Comment: If you have only 26 vc, why do you use '%99' ??

Answer (score 1):

You could pack your view controllers into an array, then roll dice for the array index to use.

Perhaps something along these lines :

```
UIViewController *randomVC = viewControllerList[arc4random() % [viewControllerList count]];
[self presentViewController:randomVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```